# VB.Net DataBase Add Row Not Working After Reset Command

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am creating a database in which data from an sql database can be recorded, saved, edited, etc. I am running into a problem in which once I hit the reset function for my dataset it will not allow me to add a row after the fact. It is almost like it adds the row but does not become visible because it gives the error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TrackMain$'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TrackMain$'. The duplicate key value is (20).
The statement has been terminated.'

Here is my code for creating the dataset from sql:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Connection String Placeholder")
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrackMain$", connection)
    Adapter.Fill(Table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
    bind_data()
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0)) + 1
End Sub
```

Here is my code for adding a row:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr(0) = nextId
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    nextId += 1

End Sub
```

Here is the code for resetting the dataset:

```
 Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Connection String Placeholder")
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrackMain$", connection)
    Adapter.Fill(Table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table


End Sub
```

I need to be able to add rows properly even after I reset the unsaved data.
Please let me know if you have any ideas or need more information. Everything is appreciated!

Here is a picture of the table and how I have primary key set:
[image]

Comment: In the actual DB, you've specified a primary key.  Have you set that to Identity?  Maybe if you could show use the Create Table script for that particular table

Comment: the initial value of `nextId` is the value of the first column of the last row in the data table plus 1, every time you click Button2, `nextId` will add 1.
You need to check your DataBase and make sure that the primary key in the database is different from the value of `NextID`, if you need further help, please provide more details about `TrackMain` table.

Comment: @Xingyu Zhao I have my primary key set to Row# and maybe that is my issue? I just assumed that column is what I should set it to because I was not planning on having any duplicate numbers. But that is most likely the same as NetID but I am a little confused to as why that should matter.

Comment: @Hursey I added the Table but had the same question as the comment to Xingyu Zhao

Comment: You set the identity property in the table design, this actually has very little to do with your front end vb.net code.  If you post the create table sql script as I originally commented to confirm

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the type of `Row#` to int and make it auto increment.
For example:

[image]

So values in `Row#`cloumn will be ordered when adding new rows, then
reset the `nextId` if you want to reset the dataset.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    ...
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0)) + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I set Row# to identity and auto increment but the datagrid still shows the numbers as skipping. Not sure if I was clear enough when asking the question but I would like the databse to automatically or on button click if needed to sort and order the numbers so if the row numbers went (3,4,6,8) I want them to be simply (1,2,3,4). Thanks for your time already on this question I appreciate it.

Comment: @PasskyyCode I am now realizing I did in fact ask a related but different question in my original post

Comment: @PasskyyCode I update my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300855/visual-basic-add-row-function-not-working-after-reset-function), and you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here. You are determining your nextId value from the last row in your grid. The second you sort the grid on a non-primary key field, you'll get the wrong value. Also, if someone else is adding to the database at the same time you will get the wrong value. Using column positions with a `SELECT *` (instead of using column names) will also bite you down the track if you ever delete a column, etc.

The best solution is to determine the new primary key value on the database server when you INSERT. This could be either using an IDENTITY (auto-incrementing) column, or you could SELECT MAX(primarykeyfieldname) in the VALUES part of your INSERT, or something like that.

Comment: would it be easier and more efficient to simply make Row# auto increment and would that still update once a row is added or deleted? Also in order to get away from Select * do I list every column name and search? I want the entire dataset to be shown so is why I used Select * but I understand how the select * can cause problems.

Comment: Yes if you make your primary key column an IDENTITY (= auto increment) type, then you don't need to put it in the INSERT statement - the server sets it automatically. Normally you wouldn't use a FLOAT type but an INT for a primary key. `SELECT *` is fine for displaying read-only, but if you want to edit in your grid you should list all the column names in your SELECT. Also be aware that `DataGridView.Rows()` is a _view_ of the underlying dataset, so you will probably need to use the `DataBoundItem` property to access the underlying `DataRow`