# Visual Basic Add Row Function Not Working After Reset Function

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I will clarify my question. Here is background:

Creating a Database in Visual Studio 2019 using Visual Basic
Database consists of a list of Devices and Serial Numbers etc. that I must have account of
I have search functions, filtering functions, and a few editing functions

The problem I am encountering is that once I click the reset button (supposed to reset the dataviewgrid unsaved changes back to last saved changes) the add row function no longer works. The code throws no error but simply refuses to add a new row when clicking the button (Before hitting the reset button the add row button works fine)

Here is how I populate my database using sql:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Connection String Placeholder")
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrackMain$", connection)
    Adapter.Fill(Table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table

    bind_data()
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0)) + 1

End Sub
```

I am also attempting to order my first column numerically and therefore I have the NextID value there as well and in my add row function (which may be the culprit)

Here is the add row and then reset function:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr(0) = nextId
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    nextId += 1

End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Connection String Placeholder")
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrackMain$", connection)
    Adapter.Fill(Table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0)) + 1
End Sub
```

If any further questions please let me know, and thank you

Edit: Here is my bind_data() Sub

```
Private Sub bind_data()
    connection.Open()
    Dim cmdTxt As String = "SELECT * FROM TrackMain$"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(New SqlCommand(cmdTxt, connection))
    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim source As BindingSource = New BindingSource With {
                                .DataSource = dt
                              }
    DataGridView1.DataSource = source

End Sub
```

Comment: Your connection, table, and adapter are only scoped to the load event or reset button, depending on which happened last. Again, `bind_data()` shows up and I don't know what it does, but you only call it in load. Did you try adding it to reset? I've seen a lot of your questions with your connection being scoped this way... I am against scoping the connection at the class level unless you are going to dispose of it properly and I would say you should narrow the scope with a `Using...` but maybe it won't work for you. But at least only have *one* instance of the items I mentioned. That's a start.

Comment: And I meant to add (but ran out of characters) maybe you should declare your connection at the class level in your case even though I am generally against that.

Comment: @djv I tried adding bind_data() to the reset command but it only added a whole new set of data under the already existing data. I put my bind_data() sub above in my question now. I will also look into how to use the Using command as well but am not too familiar with it as of now. But appreciate you taking the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the whole code of my test, and the code works for me.

```
Private dt As DataTable = New DataTable
Private da As SqlDataAdapter
Private connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("connection string")
Dim nextId As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bind_data()
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0)) + 1
End Sub

' Update database by DataGridView.'
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(i)

        If Not row.IsNewRow AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value Is Nothing Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    da.Update(dt)
End Sub

' Add new Row.'
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr(0) = nextId
    dt.Rows.Add(nextId)
    nextId += 1
End Sub

' Reset the dt and DataGridView.'
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    dt.Clear()
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrueTrack", connection)
    Adapter.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0)) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub bind_data()
    connection.Open()
    Dim cmdTxt As String = "SELECT * FROM TrueTrack"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(New SqlCommand(cmdTxt, connection))
    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim source As BindingSource = New BindingSource With {
                                    .DataSource = dt
                                  }
    DataGridView1.DataSource = source
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

---

Edit:
DataBase design(cancel auto-Increment of 'Id' ):

[image]

You can refer to the following code to sort the DataGridView by 'Id'.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Me.DataGridView1.Sort(Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Id"), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
End Sub
```

Then change the code to remove the DataGridView row.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
    End If
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value) + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Same problem even after trying this fix, I also attempted to add bind_data() into my reset command as a comment above offered but this led to a whole duplicate table of values being added to the already existing table.

Comment: I think the problem is that I am creating a new table and not resetting the already existing one? How would I properly go about that? Thanks a million once again @Xingyu Zhao

Comment: @PasskyyCode I have updated my code, and you can take a look. Hope it could be helpful.

Comment: I really appreciate it, the code works for me as well except for one problem. If I edit a row value or in your case an id value and hit save and then reset. the number changes to simply be the next number. For example I changed a value from the number 22 to the number 1 and when I reset after saving the number ended up changing back to 24 which is the greatest number in the table now. I want it to fall into place as number one and be the first row after I reset it if possible. Are you experiencing this as well? @Xingyu Zhao

Comment: In addition to my comment before this, I was just fiddling with the code and while I was using the functions the row# actually self ordered after I inputted the numbers unlike how  described before. However, once I clicked the save button it returned an error and when returning to the code it refuses to do this again and is back to the way I described it in the earlier comment. I will continue to test and will update this if I find anything new. Thanks again

Comment: nextID seems to think it is 40ish even though it should be 20s. I even deleted the nextID =+1 on the row function to get the number of nextID to the correct spot and used the delete -= 1 to do so but after I did that and saved the nextID was back to 40 once I ran the code.

Comment: @PasskyyCode I edited the answer, and you can see the latest code.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I accepted the code you provided as answer.